# Why does my Socket.io client disconnect and re-connect from an Express server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, arduino

I have an Arduino + EMG sensor connected to an Express server. The server uses the 'johnny-five' and 'socketIo' modules to connect to the board and displays the sensor data. The data currently comes through fine however the issue is that the Socket connection appears to drop and re-connect very frequently which then delays the data being sent to a React front end (also served by the Express server).

The code in the server file looks like this:

```
board.on("ready", () => {
  const mySensor = new five.Sensor("A0");

  io.on("connection", socket => {
    console.log("New client connected");

    mySensor.on("change", function(event) {

        socket.emit("emg", event);
      }
    });

    socket.on("disconnect", () => console.log("Client disconnected"));
  });
});
```

The console output looks like this:

```
{ x: 8769, y: 960 }
{ x: 8770, y: 960 }
{ x: 8771, y: 960 }
{ x: 8772, y: 960 }
{ x: 8773, y: 960 }
New client connected
New client connected
New client connected
New client connected
New client connected
New client connected
New client connected
New client connected
{ x: 8774, y: 959 }
{ x: 8775, y: 959 }
```

Where 'x' is a generic counter and 'y' is the sensor data (scaled 1-1000).

I understand that node limits the amount of listeners on an event as I was also getting the following error

```
MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected.
```

I believe what's happening is: 
- The connection occurs
- It sends data 
- The connection is dropped
- A new connection is made 
- The old event listeners aren't removed hence the node error.

I also believe that the socket connection itself should be able to handle the frequency of data so I am unsure why the connection keeps dropping.

I've tried delaying various parts of the process in order to limit the amount of data being sent in case this is the issue but this didn't work.

So my question is how do I prevent the connection dropping, or if it does, how do I clean up the old connections to at least resolve the node error?

Comment: Sounds like the client is keep creating new connections.

Comment: You need to make a Minimal, Reproducible Example and post it here. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Judging from repetitive data received, are you constantly looping on your arduino code without delay?

Comment: @hcheung No the repetitive data is just because the sensor is on a desk so it's spiking at a consistently high level. I've thought about adding a delay but not sure how I'd go about it

Comment: Did you ever make progress with this? I'm having problems with frequent disconnections/reconnections and I'm trying to get them under control.